# Difference of subsets of integers with $A-A=2 \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-2k,2k\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there any subset $A$ of integers such that $A-A= 2\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-2k,2k\}$, for some integer $k$?

($A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$, and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of even integers.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{0,2,4,...,2k-2,4k,4k+2,4k+4,...,6k-2,8k,8k+2,8k+4,...\}$

Clearly $A-A$ is a subset of $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $A-A$ does not contain $2k$ or $-2k$. Also (it needs to be shown and can be shown by induction or by calculations) any other even number belongs to $A-A$.

The only problem is that I can't write $A$ in set notation form. Hope you can do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It turns out that any integer can be represented as the sum of four squares by Lagrange's four square theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem). So if you consider the set $S=2\{a^2+b^2,a^2-b^2,-a^2+b^2,-a^2-b^2|(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2, a \neq b\}$, you have $S-S = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Now, if you take $S' = 2\{a^2+b^2,a^2-b^2,-a^2+b^2,-a^2-b^2|(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2, a \neq b\} \setminus \{2,-2\}$, can you reach the numbers $2$ and $-2$? And other even numbers?

Comment: What is your $A$. Clearly $S$ or $S'$ can't be $A$.

Comment: I don't think this $A=S'$ works correct!

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand You mean $A=S'$ works correctly?

Comment: @ Arghya Chakraborty No. It seems that it does not work correctly (but I'm not sure).